# Elements in a bootstrap grid not in-line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a basic image gallery as part of a web development course to practice the use of the bootstrap grid. However, I have an issue. I have 9 images I am trying to display and when I use the same image 9 times it displays exactly how I want it to: with 3 images per row (in lg mode). However, when I change these images so that each one is different, some of them get knocked onto the next row. I am guessing this is to do with fact that the images are not all the same size, so I tied to add  a style in my css sheet as follows:

```
.thumbnail {
   height: 100px;
}
```

However, then they do appear on different rows but they overlap each other.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="image.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true"></span> IMGS</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera" aria-hidden="true"></span> Image Gallery</h1>
        <p>A bunch of beautiful images I didn't take!</p>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1431631927486-6603c868ce5e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=0fea28ab03f5eb3910a742c5574c3a2e">
            </div>
        </div>          

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1439209306665-700c9bca794c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=99599dfef000773b04c0c9e476d0d57b">
            </div>
        </div>          

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1467189386127-c4e5e31ee213?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=f046d8bb80a4a493975a65c4b13137b4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>              
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1467404899198-ccadbcd96b91?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=66eef8db7a0aa4119c6c8d7ba211f79f">
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473654729523-203e25dfda10?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=c43d1c1c1733a34791a8e583abd2bc06">
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460891053196-b9d4d9483d9b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=a9aab8c8b84652680a27e93d0d8cbae6">
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1421629819184-d73cb1293106?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=c50d1100bf3d617b8645930c1a5f02ff">
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311530779-5241f5a29892?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=a5e435af2037f50eb837e49fcddf1aa9">
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1474496517593-015d8b59450d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=49563d997d36faad03833ddab8d15c0a">
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>  

</div>

<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"   integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone can help would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have overridden some required classes. Try opening in full width of browser.

```css
.thumbnail>img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="image.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true"></span> IMGS</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera" aria-hidden="true"></span> Image Gallery</h1>
        <p>A bunch of beautiful images I didn't take!</p>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1431631927486-6603c868ce5e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=0fea28ab03f5eb3910a742c5574c3a2e">
            </div>
        </div>          

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1439209306665-700c9bca794c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=99599dfef000773b04c0c9e476d0d57b">
            </div>
        </div>          

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1467189386127-c4e5e31ee213?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=f046d8bb80a4a493975a65c4b13137b4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>              
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1467404899198-ccadbcd96b91?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=66eef8db7a0aa4119c6c8d7ba211f79f">
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473654729523-203e25dfda10?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=c43d1c1c1733a34791a8e583abd2bc06">
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460891053196-b9d4d9483d9b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=a9aab8c8b84652680a27e93d0d8cbae6">
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1421629819184-d73cb1293106?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=c50d1100bf3d617b8645930c1a5f02ff">
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311530779-5241f5a29892?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=a5e435af2037f50eb837e49fcddf1aa9">
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1474496517593-015d8b59450d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=49563d997d36faad03833ddab8d15c0a">
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>  

</div>

<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"   integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```